# Search REST API for documents modified by logged in user

Tags: search, sharepoint-rest-api

I am working on a query to get the documents modifies by logged in user. I am able to get the documents with the specific file extension.

```
var myurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/search/query?'+
"Querytext='* AND " +
    "(FileExtension:doc OR FileExtension:docx OR FileExtension:ppt OR FileExtension:pptx OR FileExtension:xls OR FileExtension:xlsx OR FileExtension:pdf OR ContentTypeId:0x010100F3754F12A9B6490D9622A01FE9D8F012*)'"+
'&sortlist=\'LastModifiedTime:descending\'&RowLimit=10';

function onQuerySuccess2(data) {
    var results = data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results;
     $.each(results, function (index, result) {
            var modifiedTime = result.Cells.results[9].Value;
            console.log(modifiedTime);
     });
}

function onQueryError(error){
    console.log(error);
}

$.ajax({ url: myurl, method: "GET", headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, success: onQuerySuccess2, error: onQueryError });
```

The above piece of code is working properly. The only thing pending is to show the modified by currently logged in user. For this, I am adding the

&querytemplate=\'modifiedby:{User}\'

So my query becomes:

```
var myurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/search/query?'+
"Querytext='* AND " +
    "(FileExtension:doc OR FileExtension:docx OR FileExtension:ppt OR FileExtension:pptx OR FileExtension:xls OR FileExtension:xlsx OR FileExtension:pdf OR ContentTypeId:0x010100F3754F12A9B6490D9622A01FE9D8F012*)'"+
'&sortlist=\'LastModifiedTime:descending\'&RowLimit=10&querytemplate=\'modifiedby:{User}\'';
```

But then specific file extension filtering stops working. What am I doing wrong? any guess.?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the querytext, you can directly specify it in the query template itself

Try and modify the below endpoint:

```
var myurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/search/query?'+
"queryTemplate='* ModifiedBy:{User} AND " +
    "(FileExtension:doc OR FileExtension:docx OR FileExtension:ppt OR FileExtension:pptx OR FileExtension:xls OR FileExtension:xlsx OR FileExtension:pdf OR ContentTypeId:0x010100F3754F12A9B6490D9622A01FE9D8F012*)'"+
'&sortlist=\'LastModifiedTime:descending\'&RowLimit=10';

function onQuerySuccess2(data) {
    var results = data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results;
     $.each(results, function (index, result) {            
            var modifiedTime = result.Cells.results[9].Value;
            console.log(modifiedTime);
     });
}

function onQueryError(error){
    console.log(error);
}

$.ajax({ url: myurl, method: "GET", headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, success: onQuerySuccess2, error: onQueryError });
```

Comment: hey @dilip, did you try the above code ? is it working for you ?