# How to filter SharePoint search rest api results based on current logged in user

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-on-prem

I am currently using the SharePoint search rest api on a document library. The search results are coming fine. Now I have a requirement where I want to filter the search results based on the Author of the document that is uploaded.

Below is the query I am using to filter the search results based on current logged in user. The aim is to filter the results from the `Created By` column

```
var url = "http:../_api/search/query?querytext='AnyText+AND+Author:{User}+AND+ListId:a87b68a9-06fd-421c-ae0e-c93416e7e612+AND+IsDocument=True'";
```

This query is not returning any results. However if I pass the username hard-coded the results are coming as expected. e.g.

```
 var url = "http:../_api/search/query?querytext='AnyText+AND+Author:Test User (Company)+AND+ListId:a87b68a9-06fd-421c-ae0e-c93416e7e612+AND+IsDocument=True'";
```

So the above query works fine.

So my question is, Is there a way to pass the current logged in user in the `Author`.

```
Author:{User}
Author:{User.Title}
```

Unfortunately the above approach is not working fine as I think the api is not get the current user.

Source:  [Link 1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/207269/search-content-webpart-only-show-documents-from-current-user)  [Link 2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224966/search-rest-api-for-documents-modified-by-logged-in-user)

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `queryTemplate` parameter instead of `queryText`.

Modify your endpoint somewhat as below :

```
var url = "http:../_api/search/query?queryTemplate='AnyText AND Author:{User}
AND ListId:a87b68a9-06fd-421c-ae0e-c93416e7e612 AND IsDocument=True'";
```

When you use `queryTemplate` , SharePoint transforms tokens inside it to a value that is understandable to it i.e `{User}` get transformed to the current user or `{searchTerms}` gets replaced with the actual value used in the search box etc.

When you use `queryText`, it will understand plain text so that's why i guess you need to manually write the actual user name.

Reference - [SharePoint Search REST API overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview)

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to change the query at a moments notice perhaps it would be an idea to either use SourceID or perhaps SourceName / SourceLevel as per

https://www.techmikael.com/2015/01/how-to-query-using-result-source-name.html

Comment: I don't know how can I use this for my issue

Comment: Create the proper kql query in a search resultat source and refer to it by source id